# PayMill SDK iOS swift 3.0 Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, paymill

I'm trying to use PayMill SDK in a Swift project.
I used CocoaPods as described by PayMill, the framework, and it generated 'Pods_PayMilDSK'

After that I tried to import it on my file but I can't get access to any to the functions included in the framework.

I also tried to import the framework directly in my project but I can't access the PayMillSDK framework (i.e. import does not 'see' it).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Rodolphe

Answer (score 0):

After running `pod install` You should always `Build` your project, `cmd + B`, because your project still hasn't read the contents of the library you just installed.

Also make sure you're using the `.xcworkspace` and not the `.xcodeproj`

Answer (score 0):

I can now make the import of the PAyMill module but functions are not available
[image]